# How to get twitter tweets in json form using twitter username

Tags: twitter, tweets, tweetstream

How to get twitter tweets in json form using twitter username.
Is there any way to get latest tweets using php curl in json format.

Comment: Do some research and give it a try first and then show your code and ask for help if you get stuck: https://dev.twitter.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

This is a [Latest tweets Joomla Module](http://www.walkswithme.net/latest-tweets-joomla-module) you can download and extract the files check the source code it will help to develop something that match your requirement.

Hope its helps..